# Problems with recording Kinect depth using OpenNI -- "The file is corrupted!"

Tags: kinect, recording, openni

This is how I setup the recording in my app:

```
    xn::NodeInfoList recordersList;
    rc = context.EnumerateProductionTrees(XN_NODE_TYPE_RECORDER, NULL, recordersList);
    CHECK_RC(rc, "enumerate recorders");
    xn::NodeInfo chosen = *recordersList.Begin();

    recorder = new xn::Recorder();
    rc = recorder->Create(context, "oni");
    CHECK_RC(rc, "create recorder");
    rc = context.CreateProductionTree(chosen, *recorder);
    CHECK_RC(rc, "create production tree");
    rc = recorder->SetDestination(XN_RECORD_MEDIUM_FILE, "KinectLog.oni");
    CHECK_RC(rc, "set destination for recording");
    rc = recorder->AddNodeToRecording(depthGenerator, XN_CODEC_16Z_EMB_TABLES);
    CHECK_RC(rc, "add node to recording");
```

Then I call `rc = context.WaitAnyUpdateAll();` about 30 times per second; everything works, I can see the Kinect input on my screen etc.

Everything seems to go fine, but when I try to open the resulting `KinectLog.oni` in the sample `NiViewer`, I get:

```
jan@mbp ~/OpenNI/Samples/Bin/x64-Release $ ./NiViewer ~/devel/k/KinectLog.oni
Open failed: The file is corrupted!
Press any key to continue . . .
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, I forgot to do:

```
recorder->Release();
delete recorder;
```

at the end.